# Unable to Install Tensorflow with Python 3 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: python-3.x, installation, tensorflow

**I have already have a virtual environment installation of Tensorflow on my computer, although it runs Python 2.7**. **Now I want to work with Tensorflow running in Python 3.5.**

For Python 3, I've created a virtual environment since the default Python environment on my computer is Python 2.7. I'm attempting a [Pip installation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/get_started/os_setup.html#pip-installation) of Tensorflow in a Python 3 virtual environment that I have named `py3k`. The installation procedure throws errors that I'm finding difficulty in debugging.

**Here's what I did:**

```
    anirudh@anirudh-Vostro-3445:~$ source activate py3k
    (py3k) anirudh@anirudh-Vostro-3445:~$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.10.0rc0-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl
    (py3k) anirudh@anirudh-Vostro-3445:~$ sudo pip3 install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL

    /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pip-8.1.2-py3.2.egg/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py:80: UserWarning: Support for Python 3.0-3.2 has been dropped. Future versions will fail here.
      warnings.warn(msg)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
        load_entry_point('pip==8.1.2', 'console_scripts', 'pip3')()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 337, in load_entry_point
        return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2280, in load_entry_point
        return ep.load()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1990, in load
        entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pip-8.1.2-py3.2.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
        from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pip-8.1.2-py3.2.egg/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
        from pip.download import path_to_url
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pip-8.1.2-py3.2.egg/pip/download.py", line 36, in <module>
        from pip.utils.ui import DownloadProgressBar, DownloadProgressSpinner
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pip-8.1.2-py3.2.egg/pip/utils/ui.py", line 15, in <module>
        from pip._vendor.progress.bar import Bar, IncrementalBar
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pip-8.1.2-py3.2.egg/pip/_vendor/progress/bar.py", line 48
        empty_fill = u'∙'
                          ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

`cp35` from `https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.10.0rc0-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl` means C python 3.5
You have python 3.2 on your machine
I recommend installing Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: I do not have the option to upgrade to Ubuntu 15.04 unfortunately.

Comment: try to install python 3.4 or 3.5 instead of 3.2 and make sure the tensorflow pip wheel corresponds